# Understanding explicit promise construction anti pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

[CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance) highlighted in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909391/destructuring-something-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment94663454_53909391) advised me to **avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern** with reference to to [following question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Frankly, Speaking, I am new to JS and node and I haven't used promise a lot. I went and read those article but either I was unable to comprehend or unable to relate or maybe somewhere my understanding of promises have been vague/wrong all together

So I decided to ask this question in a new thread and seek for help.

## So what am I doing and why am I doing it

I am creating helper/common function which I could use to keep my code tidy and if in case I want to change anything inside function at anytime, I don't have to manually change every function.

So these are the functions I have made

```
//Find user by email Address 
const findUserByEmail = (emailAddress) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     User.findOne({email: emailAddress}).then(response => {
        resolve(res)
      }).catch(error => {
        reject("Error in findUserByEmail", error);
      })
    })
}

//Create User 
const createNewUser = (newUserDetails) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      new User({
         fullName: newUserDetails.fullName,
         email: newUserDetails.email,
         image: newUserDetails.image,
         gender: newUserDetails.gender,
         age: newUserDetails.age
      }).save().then((response) => {
          resolve(response)
      }).catch((error) => {
          reject("Problem in Creating New User", error)
      })
    })
}
```

#### Question 1

Now, I am assuming CertainPerformance said the excessive use of promises  because I am creating new promise  `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` when I am already using promises with mongoose `User.findOne({email: emailAddress}).then(response => {` ?

But the reason for me to create those promise was, when I call these helper function from anywhere in my app after importing

```
const { findUserByEmail } = require("./my_db_query");
```

I would probably want it return a response or throw an error in case of error

```
findUserByEmail("test@example.com").then(/*...*/).catch(/*...*/);
```

If I change my above code snippet without adding new promise

```
 function findUserByEmail  (email) {
       return User.findOne({email: email}).then(currentUser => currentUser).catch(error => error)
    }
```

#### Question 2

Then I won't probably be able to `.then` and `.catch` in `findUserByEmail("test@example.com")`**?**

And In API route of App, where I would be calling the `findUserByEmail("test@example.com")` function, I would want to do something else if there is an error (which would be different for different case and hence I cannot use it in my helper function).

#### Question 3

Does, it make sense now for doing `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` instead of doing just one  `return User.findOne(` or am I missing something?

Comment: if there is any error you can throw it and it can be caught in the caller function function findUserByEmail  (email) {
       return User.findOne({email: email}).then(currentUser => currentUser).catch(function (err) {
        // throw the error to be handled by the endpoint
        throw err;
      })
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `.findOne` already returns a `Promise`, there's no need to construct a new one with `new Promise` - instead, just *chain onto* the existing `Promise` chain with `.then` and `.catch` as needed. Such `Promise` chains can have *any number* of `.then`s and `.catch`s - just because you consume a `Promise` with one `.then` doesn't prevent you from using the same resolve value elsewhere. To illustrate:

```
makePromise()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    // Returning inside a `.then` will pass along the value to the next `.then`:
    return result;
  })
  .then((result) => {
    // this `result` will be the same as the one above
  });
```

In other words - there's no need to construct a `new Promise` every time you want to be able to use another `.then`. So:

> Then I won't probably be able to .then and .catch in findUserByEmail("test@example.com")

isn't correct - you can indeed chain onto the end of an existing Promise with as many `.then`s and `.catch`es as you want.

Note that a `.then` which only returns its parameter and does nothing else (such as `.then(currentUser => currentUser)`) is superfluous - it won't do anything at all. Also note that a `.catch` will catch *Promise rejections* and resolve to a *resolved* `Promise`. So if you do

```
function findUserByEmail(email) {
  return User.findOne({email: email})
    .then(currentUser => currentUser)
    .catch(error => error)
}
```

that `catch` means that callers of `findUserByEmail` will *not* be able to `catch` errors, because any possible errors were caught in `findUserByEmail`'s `catch`. Usually, it's a good idea to allow errors to percolate up to the *caller* of the function, that way you could, for example:

```
someFunctionThatReturnsPromise('foobar')
  .then((result) => {
    // everything is normal, send the result
    res.send(result);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // there was an error, set response status code to 500:
    res.status(500).send('there was an error');
  })
```

So, unless your `findUserByEmail` or `createNewUser` helper functions *need* to do something specific when there's an error, it would probably be best just to return the `Promise` alone:

```
const findUserByEmail = email => User.findOne(email);
const createNewUser = newUserDetails => new User(newUserDetails).save();
```

If your helper functions *do* need to do something when there's an error, then to make sure that the error gets passed along properly to the caller of the function, I'd recommend either throwing the error inside the `catch`:

```
const findUserByEmail = email => User.findOne(email)
  .catch((err) => {
    // error handling - save error text somewhere, do a console.log, etc
    throw err;
  });
```

so that you can `catch` when something else calls `findUserByEmail`. Otherwise, if you do something like

```
const findUserByEmail = email => User.findOne(email)
  .catch((err) => {
    // do something with err
    return err;
  });
```

then the caller of `findUserByEmail` will have to check *inside the `.then`* if the result is actually an error, which is weird:

```
findUserByEmail('foo@bar.com')
  .then((result) => {
    if (result instanceof Error) {
      // do something
    } else {
      // No errors
    }
  });
```

Better to throw the error in `findUserByEmail`'s `catch`, so that the consumer of `findUserByEmail` can *also* `.catch`.

Comment: I literally swear than you and @estus explained me how promise works like no one else have ever done. Thanks a ton for answering :)

Answer (score 3):

It never makes sense to create a promise with promise constructor when there's existing promise, that's why it's called promise construction antipattern.

This is a mistake, `reject("Error in findUserByEmail", error)`. `reject` accepts only 1 
argument, which is rejection reason. `error` will be ignored. It's conventionanl for an error to be `Error` object and not a string.

The function may be refactored to:

```
   const findUserByEmail = (emailAddress) => {
     return User.findOne({email: emailAddress})
     .then(response => response) // noop
     .catch(error => {
        const readableError = new Error('Error in findUserByEmail');
        readableError.originalError = error;
        throw readableError;
      });
    })
  }
```

etc.

Antipatterns don't necessary result in bad performance but they result in *code smell*. They make the code harder to read, maintain and test, also show that a developer may have a poor understanding of the subject.

Promise constructor has some insignificant performance impact. It introduces another level of nesting and contributes to callback hell - promises are supposed to help avoiding it.

> If I change my above code snippet without adding new promise <...>
>   Then I won't probably be able to .then and .catch in findUserByEmail("test@example.com")?

No, a promise can be chained with `then(...)` and `catch(...)` (which is syntactic sugar for `then(null, ...)`) as many times as needed, that's the strong side of the pattern. Notice that `catch(err => { return err })` and `catch(err => { throw err })` is not the same thing, the former catches an error, the latter rethrows it.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense now. Can you please also answer second part of the question?

Comment: I've added some explanation. I believe it already answers Q1-3. Is there something else that needs to be addressed?

Comment: when calling `findUserByEmail` function i.e `findUserByEmail("test@example.com")` , can I do `findUserByEmail("test@example.com").then(response => response).catch(error => error)` if I am not doing `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`

Comment: I updated the answer. Yes, you can, that's the point and the actual reason why `new Promise` is redundant. Notice that `.catch(error => error)` catches an error, while in `new Promise` you reject it. There should be `throw error` if you want it to be rethrown.