# Node Async/Await not working and need to implement call back

Tags: node.js, express

Have a look on my controller

```
exports.userList = async (req, res) => {
   let result = await Methods.getAllData(Campaign)
   await console.log(result, 'tr')
}
```

Here `Methods.getAllData` is a function to get all user data and the parameter `Campaign` is my Model name.

here the function..

```
methods.getAllData = (modelName)=>{
    modelName.findAll({
    }).then(value=>{
        console.log(value, 'rt')
        return value
    }).catch(err=>{
        return err
    })
}
```

1. My console.log statement is running first. I have tried to solve using aync/await but not working. I need to get the result and then I need to console that.
2. Here I have returned the data, how can I use callback as replacement of return?

Comment: You just need to return `findAll` --- `return modelName.findAll(....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to return promise from getAllData

```
const getAllData = (modelName)=>{
  return  modelName.findAll();
}

exports.userList = (req, res) => {
   const newPromise = getAllData(Campaign);

   newPromise
     .then( result => console.log('result',result))
     .catch( err => console.log('error', err))

}
```

Comment: If you get your problem solved with the help of my answer then you can make it as accepted one.

Comment: let me know if you have any  other problem.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to return the promise generated by `findAll()`. You do not need to change anything else in your code:

```
methods.getAllData = (modelName)=>{
    return modelName.findAll({ // ---------------- this is the  bug fix
    }).then(value=>{
        console.log(value, 'rt')
        return value
    }).catch(err=>{
        return err
    })
}
```

However, returning from a catch like this is bad practice because it converts the error into a regular return value. Either rethrow the error:

```
    }).catch(err=>{
        throw err
    })
```

or don't catch errors here:

```
methods.getAllData = (modelName)=>{
    return modelName.findAll({ // ---------------- this is the  bug fix
    }).then(value=>{
        console.log(value, 'rt')
        return value
    }) // ---------------------------------------- remove catch
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `getAllData` method with this code below:

**Updated:**

```js
methods.getAllData = (modelName)=>{
  return modelName.findAll();
}
```

And in your `userList`, you can make it like this code below:

```js
exports.userList = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let result = await Methods.getAllData(Campaign);
    console.log(result);
  } catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
  }
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: The function `findAll` already returns a promise. Don't wrap it in another promise - this is an anti-pattern

Comment: The function `findAll` already returns a promise. You do not need to await it. Just return it

Comment: @Rabbani_ Your bug is you forgot to return the promise. You called a function that returns a promise then you don't return anything at all

Comment: There could be other reasons, for example the OP appears to always run a `then()` on `findAll()` no matter who calls `getAllData()`. Or it could just be adhering to specific design patterns such as the repository pattern which disallows you calling database functions directly etc. In any case, you are also "creating another function to put a model in" - your argument goes against your own answer. Wrapping a promise in a promise constructor is a well-known anti-pattern and bad coding practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53910226/understanding-explicit-promise-construction-anti-pattern

Comment: @slebetman: Thank you for your advice. I really appreciate it.